# How to hide rulers, statusbar, scrollbars in GIMP persistently?

Tags: gimp, preferences

I am using GIMP 2.6.12 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I would like to hide the rulers, the status bar and the scrollbars but they keep reappearing after restarting GIMP. How do I make them disappear forever?

I have also disabled the menubar and that stays hidden, just as I want it. Why are those others misbehaving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to change the settings through Preferences Window instead of *View* Menu. Changes made through *View* Menu are not persistent, they get overwritten when you restart GIMP.

- Open the Preferences Window by navigating through *Edit* Menu → *Preferences*.
- Then in the sidebar navigate through *Image Windows* → *Appearance*.
- Here, tick/untick the appropriate check-boxes as per your preference.

[image: GIMP Preference Window]

Comment: thanks, but how come, that the menubar-hiding was persistent, even though (I think) I changed it through the view menu (? bug)

Comment: @nlognfan: Maybe.. not too sure about it.. Don't use GIMP too much.. :-)

Comment: For me, hiding the Menubar through View Menu is not persistent, you must have changed it through preference window instead :-)